# when defining an angular module - should I wrap in self executing function?

Tags: angularjs

```
(function (angular) {
   "use strict";

   angular.module('module')
   .filter('leFilter', function() { ... });

})(angular);
```

Saw this code in a new project I'm working on.
I usually just begin the module at the root of the file and dont use 'strict' mode.

```
angular.module('module')
   .filter('leFilter', function() { ... });
```

I've never ran into a single issue doing this.

In the context of an angular application, is there really anything to gain from the self-executing function and 'strict' mode?

Comment: this is really a matter of coding style, but here is a pretty good article that talks about the different approaches in detail:  http://toddmotto.com/minimal-angular-module-syntax-approach-using-an-iife/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't see any *major* benefit from running it in an IIFE(Immediately-Invoked Function Expression), especially with how good angular is about wrapping things in closures itself (such as in your filter). You will insulate yourself from naming collisions thanks to the scope created by using them, but they decrease readability. They would be a bit more useful in this regard if you stored your angular modules in variables upon instantiation and used those when adding controllers/filters/etc. rather than using the module getter, but I don't recommend doing that.

If you are using a build system such as Gulp or Grunt then it might be worth having it compile these files inside of IIFE, and leaving your source without them.

I always recommend using "use strict" because it makes you write cleaner code with less chance of having casting issues. But, again, it doesn't necessarily help you "gain" anything so much as it prevents something bad from possible occurring.

Both of these are essentially safe-guards more-so than giving you some sort of advantage.

Comment: I completely agree with the advice to let gulp/grunt preprocess the files and add function wrapping & strict mode. There is really no need to write it again and again to every file, increasing indentation. If you ever decide to remove it, changing the scripts is really easier than changing tens or hundreds of source files.

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks for expanding on that. I kind of glossed over it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read here http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/ that using 'use strict' without IIFE can result in errors. So if you're using 'use strict' it's recommended to use IIFE as well. With that said, I've decided to not use strict mode simply because my text editor catches most of the errors that strict mode is supposed to prevent such as accidental globals and duplicate function parameters. I use typescript so that prevents invalid casting. You might want to use strict mode if you're writing your js code on a notepad!

Comment: I also never use `with`, `eval()`, or immutables  so I don't need these safegaurds. As for other devs on the team, they should know to write clean javascript without these constructs.. and if they don't they won't make it past my code reviews anyways ;)

Comment: Thank you for following up. I hadn't even considered the implications that strict mode might have with concatenation. That's a great tip! Good points about IDEs catching most issues anyway as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

strict mode means you have less chance of running into type casting issue while self executing function is to avoid polluting global namespace.